# Create page not using the main 'template'

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a angular aplication (using primefacesng).

On my index.html I have a standard app-root tag.

On the app-component.html (the main app component of the app) I have the header, footer of the page. And the router-outlet.

This is working fine. When I navigate on the app my code is show in the place of the router-outlet with the header and footer.

But I need to create a page without this header and footer. Like a login page or something like this. How can I make this ?

As requested I create a stackblitz to show what I need on :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-wf6x8r

When I click on the not found button on the main page I don't want it to show the tabs at the top. Only the 'This page was not found' message and the 'go home' button.

This stackblitz is very simple in relation with the real project so I want to make as few updates as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As base components have e.g. your login-component and a shell-component.
Route to them as you are used to in your AppRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: "login",
  component: LoginComponent
},
{
  path: "",
  component: ShellComponent
}
];
```

Then create a shell-module with routing as well as a shell-component. Then add Childroutes to its routing-module (shell-routing.module.ts). The shell component includes 
header-, footer-component aswell as a second router-outlet.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: "",
component: ShellComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    ...
  }
 ...
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

So to achieve this you need to follow this approach.
Layout component which will have header, main and footer component.
If you want to render your app then you can use layout component.
You will have separate login component which will not be part of your layout.
so whenever your login path will be called you will get login component without header, footer and main

Comment: But on this case where I put the router-outlet tag ? I need to have it on my layout component because most of the pages are using the main layout. The login path is just an example.

Comment: router outlet will be in app.component.html. router outlet takes the path from routing component if you will pass login in your path then app will redirect to login only if you will pass layout then you will be navigated with header footer and main. If you need more clarification. Just provide a stackblitz example to me I will make changes into that

Comment: I edit the OP to include a simple stackblitz example.

Comment: check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-ix7jb3 I have made some changes